# Turn the page back in php code is wrong

Tags: php

I have a problem when the user is already registered I go back with the button on the browser and this page does not redirect me, I have a code so that when you enter a registered user sends it to a specific web.
presents "this page can not be displayed"
no I redirect me although I have a code that is this

```
if (isset ($ _ SESSION ['email']))
  {
     header ("location: sesion.php");
     exit ();
}
```

what is the problem

Comment: are there really spaces in this? `$ _ SESSION`

Comment: when you click back in browser, browser fetch cache page instead of new page

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.  First the page is generally cached by the browser. This can be fixed by setting the page to not cahce(one of the following methods dont need to do all).

In PHP at top of page:

```
session_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

In .htaccess:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

**Secondly your code has extra space:**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
     header("location: sesion.php");
     exit();
}
```

Comment: ohh my god :( when i put the code especially  the exit();
the page no loading, not pass not show me the message that is down the page not records  to the user is like if when read the first code stop.
:( :( :(

Comment: Any chance you are trying to run this in session.php and it is creating an infinite loop?

Comment: Also you need to have session_start(); as first line of code.  Make sure no space or anything before

Comment: i have it 
this is my code in the top
[code]<?php 

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
session_start();
//================problema 

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
     header ("location: sesion.php");
     exit ();
}

//================problema 

//pregunta si existe el pass segundo del formulario con esto no puede entrar a la web por el link si no se esta registrando 
if(!isset($_POST['rpass'])){  
header('Location: ../../index.php');
exit();
}[code]

Comment: Session needs to come first always.  It is in the manual for the command

Answer (score 0):

i have it 
this is my code in the top

```html
i have it 
this is my code in the top
[code]<?php 

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
session_start();
//================problema 

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
     header ("location: sesion.php");
     exit ();
}

//================problema 

//pregunta si existe el pass segundo del formulario con esto no puede entrar a la web por el link si no se esta registrando 
if(!isset($_POST['rpass'])){  
header('Location: ../../index.php');
exit();
}[code]
```

Comment: this is what i told you to do and it works perfectly?  why put second answer instead of checking mine?